# preg_replace question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

im trying to accomplish the following:

search for a lowercase letter followed by uppercase letter. replace this with the lowercase letter, followed by '. ', followed by the uppercase letter.

example:

```
helloAre you there
```

should become:

```
hello. Are you there
```

Comment: I've added an example to my solution for excluding iPhone

Comment: you're welcome.  When you have found a satisfactory solution, please accept an answer (green check) and optionally vote up solutions that helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '$1. $2', $str);
```

Comment: how would you go about making an exception from the rule? im using this to print meta descriptions, but i have an exeption for apple products, "iP" should not be matched :> (for iPhone, iPad and so on)

Answer (score 3):

Inserts a dot-space `.` between the lower and upper-case letters.

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/', '. ', $str);
```

To prevent `iP`, use this:

```
preg_replace('/(?!iP)([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/', '$1. ', $str);
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how your regular expression works, how it inserts a dot in-between. Will you mind if I can ask you to please share the explanation with me? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I'm wondering if preg_replace_all() is a PHP function?

Comment: @Abhay, it ends up matching a zero-width expression.  In other words, it matches a position, but no characters are replaced.  The position it finds is the position inbetween the lower-case letter and an uppercase letter.  It uses atomic lookbehind `(?<=regex)` and lookaheed `(??=regex)`assertions.

Comment: thanks for filling me in, much appreciated. I haven't heard earlier on lookbehind and lookahead; so will surely have a read on them. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `$text` is the original text you could use

```
$text = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '\1. \2', $text);
```